# String.split("\n") not working with Scanner input

Tags: java

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
String  s  = in.nextLine();
String[] strings = s.split("\\n");

for (int i = 0; i < strings.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(strings[i]);
}
```

The string isn't being split by `\n`. I can't figure out why. Example input is `Apples\nOranges\nMangoes`.

Comment: That's because the scanner is only getting the first line, `Apples`. You don't really need to split by `\n` yourself, just read multiple lines from the scanner.

Comment: You're calling `s.nextLine()` but somehow you're expecting *all* the lines to be there ???

Comment: You are calling a scanner method on an uninitialized object with `String s = s.nextLine();`, maybe it is just a typo.

Comment: Yeah that was a typo.

Comment: nextLine() strips the \n from the input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The string isn't being split by `\n`.

The string doesn't *contain* `\n`. See the Javadoc for `Scanner.nextLine()`.

If you want to read and print all the lines, you have to read all the lines. In a loop. You don't need `String.split()` for that.